# Get contact photo iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, photos

I took a photo using the contact app on my iPhone 5.  I would like to copy that photo, but there doesnt appear to be an easy way to get it.

I did some googling, but all the answers were several years old - and all of them said you could not do it.

There was *one* answer that required programming that the poster said "*supposedly* could do it", but I dont have the development tools (or working Mac) to even try.

Anyone know of a way to extract the contact photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold down on the contact photo to copy it:

[image]

Comment: ok... did that... where can i paste it?

Comment: @Keltari "*I would like to copy that photo*" :) It's up to you — what do you want to do with it?

Comment: i just want to save it to photos or somewhere i can move it to a pc

Comment: @Keltari Paste it in an email and send it to yourself?

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: UPDATE: in iOS 13 (iPhone and iPad OS), this does work, but you need to long-press for the menu, then long press the photo in the menu.

Comment: And to store it to your phone, you can create a Shortcut with 2 items: "Get clipboard" and "Save Clipboard to Recents". Then after copying the photo like above, run that shortcut and the photo will be stored in your Camera Roll - without having to send a mail to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in a text message to yourself. Send it. Then you can copy it to photos.